# Cannot find Decimal Format class in Java

Tags: java

I cant get this code to work... I don't know why.

It is the same code as in this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meKpmuUI0ds&feature=related.

The code works when this guy does it, but I get these 2 errors:

> Test.java:4: cannot fin symbol    symbol: class decimalFormat
>
> location: class Test
>
> ```
> decimalFormat decFor = new decimalFormat("0.00");
> ```
>
> ^
>
> Test.java:4: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol: class decimalFormat
>
> location: class Test
>
> ```
> decimalFormat decFor = new decimalFormat("0.00");
>
>                        ^
> ```
>
> 2 errors.

**Here's my code**:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        decimalFormat decFor = new decimalFormat("0.00");
        double money = 15.9;
        double mula = 36.6789;
        double product = money * mula;

        System.out.println(decFor.format(product));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) not `decimalFormat`, Use IDE to assist you for such mistakes

Also add

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

Comment: @Lisa In your IDE, it will auto-add imports for you. If you don't use an IDE, you have to know/find which package the class is in and add the import yourself. +1

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

check out the documentation its **DecimalFormat ** , don't forget to **import** it too

Answer (score 2):

Java class names are case sensitive and I believe the class you are after is DecimalFormat.

The convention for Java class names says they have a capital letter at the beginning, so that's an easy way to spot the error, even if you're not using an IDE.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is DecimalFormat, with capital D letter.

Answer (score 0):

to be explicit about the import then you could use

```
java.text.DecimalFormat decFor = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

This is not ideal because it makes the code look a bit more messy. If this works then you can add the import

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
```